# What does "width" do in meta viewport tag?

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta-tags

I read that `width` in metaviewport tag defines the virtual width of the viewport and then this viewport is scaled up to fill the screen as per the `initial-scale`. The problem is that I do not see any difference when I change the `width = device-width` to any other value like `width = 600` or `width = 1200`. Following two versions are rendered same:

**`width = 600` :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width= 600px, initial-scale = 2">
<style>


    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {      
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
     }
     ul {
      list-style: none;
     }
    .container {
      width: 96px;
      height: 96px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #333;     
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container"> Hello

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**`width = 50` :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width= 50, initial-scale = 2">
<style>


    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {      
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
     }
     ul {
      list-style: none;
     }
    .container {
      width: 96px;
      height: 96px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #333;     
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container"> Hello

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browsers and operating systems are you using to test this?

Comment: @Quentin I am using windows 7 and google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Meta viewport is used to help render pages on atypically sized screens.

Chrome on a Windows 7 desktop scaled screen isn't going to support it.

To see any effect you would need to use something like Chrome for Android or Mobile Safari on iOS on a smart phone sized display.

Comment: I tried using inspect element and then set different resolutions in mobile mode. Every thing else in viewport tag is working, like `initial-scale`.